# What is the meaning of "the great white whale of modern science"

Tags: meaning

In the context , what does this sentence mean, please help me

[New York Times:](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/05/science/chasing-the-higgs-boson-how-2-teams-of-rivals-at-CERN-searched-for-physics-most-elusive-particle.html)
*Dr. Sharma and his colleagues had every reason to believe that they were closing in on **the Great White Whale of modern science: the Higgs boson**, a particle whose existence would explain all the others then known and how they fit together into the jigsaw puzzle of reality.*

Comment: You ask for the meaning "in context" but you don't provide any context!  Please provide the **source**.  And also any background that you've understood.  For example, do you know "the great white whale" called "Moby Dick"?  If not, then you haven't done any prior investigation.

Comment: Refer to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20whale). Quite synonym of [search for the Holy Grail](https://www.dictionary.com/e/holy-grail/).

Comment: [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20whale) ***white whale** or less commonly **great white whale** : something (such as a goal or object) that is obsessively pursued.*

Answer (score 2):

In the novel *Moby Dick*, the Captain of the boat is obsessed with catching a "great (ie big) white whale", that he has named "Moby Dick".  So by analogy, "The great white whale of modern science" is the thing that modern scientists are (or were) obsessively trying to find.

In the paragraph, it is put next to "the Higgs boson" and the Higgs boson was the "great white whale of modern science".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BoburbekJamoliddinov On this site, if you like someone's answer to your question and it satisfies you, it's a courtesy to click the check mark beside the answer to mark it as "accepted". This gives the answerer a small [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) boost.